# Limits for an user to make API Calls

Tags: api, integration

I know that we can make callouts based on Salesforce edition and its licenses, is there any limitations on user level ? i.e How many API requests can an user make in 24 hour period ?

Answer (score 3):

The API limits are for Incoming calls, ie From 3rd party to SF.

There is no limit for outgoing callouts from SF to external system/endpoint except platform limitation of 100 callouts in 1 transaction and no callout after DML

Answer (score 2):

API calls are metered per organization, not per user. Assuming a user has the Api Enabled permission, they can theoretically make as many API calls as the organization has available, subject to other limits, such as the concurrent request limit. In small orgs, this is pretty to do, while in really large orgs, a user might need to exceed 100 API calls per second to max out the org's limits.

Comment: API enabled is for incoming calls not outgoing callouts?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Admittedly, the question is confusing on second read--the subject suggests outbound from Salesforce, but the rest appears to be about inbound calls.

Comment: @sfdcfox it's right. The question is about call in.

Comment: @sfdcfox  Can a platform user license with API enabled on the profile(user license: Salesforce Platform) will be able to make callouts. Need to build an integration with google maps and that will be used by the user with Platform license.

Comment: @user2815826 API Enabled does not affect callouts. A user wouldn't need this permission to make a callout. And yes, they should be able to make callouts just as any other user can.

Comment: @sfdcfox thanks!